# error: cannot find symbol purchase

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class CreatePurchase {
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         Purchase purchase=new Purchase();
         Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter the details: ");
         while(true)
         {
             System.out.print("Enter invoice number[between 1000 and 8000]: ");
             int i=s.nextInt();
             if(i>=1000 && i<=8000){purchase.setInvoiceNumber(i);break;}
             else System.out.println("Wrong entry,enter again");
         }
         while(true)
         {
             System.out.print("Enter amount of purchase[should be non-negative]: ");
             int i=s.nextInt();
             if(i>=0){purchase.setAmountOfSales(i);break;}
             else System.out.println("Wrong entry,enter again");
         }
         purchase.display();
     }
 }
```

This is the exact error messages I keep getting:

```
C:\Users\Kenneth\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CreatePurchase\src\createpurchase  \CreatePurchase.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
     Purchase purchase=new Purchase();
symbol:   class Purchase
location: class CreatePurchase
C:\Users\Kenneth\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CreatePurchase\src\createpurchase\CreatePurchase.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
     Purchase purchase=new Purchase();
symbol:   class Purchase
location: class CreatePurchase
2 errors
```

I have no idea how to fix it and netbeans is not showing anything wrong with the code. Help is appreciated.

Here is the Purchase code, which compiled and ran fine.

```
class Purchase
 {
     int invoiceNumber;
     int amountOfSales;
     double amountOfSalesTax;
     static double rate=7.5;
     public void setInvoiceNumber(int i)
     {
         invoiceNumber=i;
     }
     public void setAmountOfSales(int a)
     {
         amountOfSales=a;
         amountOfSalesTax=(7.5*a)/100;
     }
     public void display()
     {
         System.out.println("The deatils are:");
         System.out.println("Invoice Number: "+invoiceNumber);
         System.out.println("Amount of Sales: "+amountOfSales);
         System.out.println("Amount of sales tax: "+amountOfSalesTax);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Did you import the `Purchase` class?

Comment: You need to show the Purchase class code.

Comment: is Purchase class in the same package as CreatePurchase? If not, you need to import it.